# Remove iAd banner from one scene

Tags: ios, swift, iad

I have a basic game created with 3 scenes - Start, GameScene, and Gameover Scene. I've implemented iAd banners using the code shown below. This was simple for me, as a beginner, to do. However, the banner ad seems to be impacting the frame rate during game play so I want it to be removed/hidden during the game scene. Is there an easy way to accomplish this?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.canDisplayBannerAds = true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the game scene where you'd like to hide the `ADBannerView` set `self.canDisplayBannerAds = false`. Alternatively, you could create the `ADBannerView` programmatically and set its `hidden` property to `true`.